# how can i round time up when calculating time as a double in c#.net

Tags: c#

here is my code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ans = double.Parse(txtb1.Text) - double.Parse(txtb2.Text);

        string time = ans.ToString();
        double seconds = TimeSpan.Parse(time); // Duration is not working

        label1.Text = seconds.ToString();  
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

i am trying to round up from after the point i.e if its greater than or equals to 60 it should add one to the integer and subtract it from the mantissa(decimal) 
what i mean is that if i have a value of 1.70, i should have 2.10 i.e 2hrs 10min

Comment: Define "round up". Should 1.1s go to 1s or 2s? (I assume 1.5s..1.9s would go to 2s)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Converting a double to a string to then try to parse it as a `TimeSpan` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What is in txtb1.Text & txtb2.Text ? Could You provide sample data? And expected results?

Comment: `double seconds = TimeSpan.Parse(time); ` is not working because the return value is a `TimeSpan`. What is the unit of measure that you are looking for?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean. what i meant is that if i have a value of 1.70, i should have 2.10 i.e 2hrs 10min

Comment: is 1.70 equal to 1h 70m or 1.7 hours?

Comment: @mcNets following the logic of 2.1 = 2H 10 min it 1.7 commands to be 1h 70 min

Comment: @MongZhu there is no logic getting 1.70 from a textbox where 70 means minutes.

Comment: 1h.70min wanna convert that to 2hr.10min

Comment: which values are stored in textb1 and textb2? why substracting txtb2 from txtb1 the result is = 1.70?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate the double value of 1.70 to Hours and minutes with your logic you should do the following.

```
var dbl = 1.70;

var hours = Math.Floor(dbl);
var minutes = (dbl - hours) * 100;
var ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours).Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));

Console.WriteLine("{0}h {1}min", Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes);
```

If your value is actually "{Hours}.{Minutes}" and could have "100.500" for 100hours 500minutes then you would need to change how you parse the value to get hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `Math.Ceiling(ans)`.
It will always round up, even if the decimal value is below 0.5

Answer (score 0):

If you want to correct a time string from the format that you posted I would suggest to use this method:

```
public static double correctTime(string commaTime)
{
    double d = Convert.ToDouble(commaTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    int basis = (int)d;
    // if the number after the comma is larger than 0.6 then just add 0.4
    return d - basis > 0.6 ? d = d + 0.4 : d;
}
```

As for the conversion into a `TimeSpan` you need to get your number into the right format:

```
string s = "1.7";

double cor_s = correctTime(s);
string time = cor_s.ToString("00.00").Replace('.', ':'); // or
```

now you can parse it into a `TimeSpan`:

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.Parse(time);
```

or if you want only the seconds:

```
double total_seconds = TimeSpan.Parse(time).TotalSeconds;
```

I hope I understood your problem correctly